# Windows 8 remove Alt+R key shortcut

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to remove the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut from Windows 8 settings. I have this setting on other software and this shortcut of Windows conflict by other. How can I remove that?

In *Control Panel*, I cannot find settings for this shortcut and I cannot find any software to change that.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?  [`Alt+R` isn't even a Windows 8 shortcut.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2012/08/28/windows-8-shortcuts.aspx)

Comment: @Ramhound remove this shortcut keybord from windows setting

Comment: By default it isn't a Windows shortcut though

Comment: @Ramhound after press this keys windows 8 execute `run` application

Comment: The default shortcut for that should be `Windows Key + R` if `ALT + R` is performing that operation you have a third-party application that is doing that.  I provided a link to ALL Windows 8 shortcuts except those that changed in 8.1 but that wasn't one of them.